# Visual Studio Typescript Intellisense doesn't respect tsconfig.json baseUrl

Tags: visual-studio, typescript

I've got a web project in Visual Studio 2017 with a large TypeScript codebase. When I do a TypeScript build, I get no errors, and the resulting JavaScript is correct. However, my intellisense shows errors for any imports using a path based on the `baseUrl` configured in my tsconfig.json.

For example:
[image]

When I change these to a relative path, the errors go away:
[image]

Other editors' code inspection doesn't seem to have a problem with the former. We've confirmed it working in VS Code and JetBrains Rider.

My tsconfig.json is as follows:

```js
{
 "compilerOptions": {
  "noImplicitAny": false,
  "noEmitOnError": true,
  "strictNullChecks": true,
  "removeComments": false,
  "sourceMap": true,
  "target": "es5",
  "module": "amd",
  "moduleResolution": "node",
  "baseUrl": "./Content/ts"
 },
 "exclude": [
  "node_modules"
 ],
 "compileOnSave": true
}
```

I've tried as many different Visual Studio settings as I can find, but nothing seems to affect whether intellisense is able to find the modules. Again, the compiler itself has no issue finding them and building.

Update: Forgot to include that we also had the `<TypeScriptBaseUrl>` property defined in the .csproj file, set to the same value that's present in our tsconfig.json. This causes the TS build within Visual Studio to succeed, but doesn't seem to affect Intellisense.

Comment: Under `shared/` can you add `package.json` with `{"name": "shared"}`?

Comment: @ExplosionPills Added that file, and included it in the VS web project, but it didn't seem to have any effect.

Comment: Can you create a minimal project and see if the issue still occurs, if it does may be a bug you may need to report?

Comment: @TarunLalwani Just confirmed that I still see this issue with a brand new MVC app. May indeed need to be filed as a bug.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Turns out the tsconfig.json file needs to be included in the project to get Intellisense to be happy. Not sure why the `<TypeScriptBaseUrl>` setting wasn't good enough. That's probably still a bug that needs to be reported.

Answer (score 0):

In case somebody encounters a similar problem in an SDK-style project, you can add this to your `.csproj`:

```xml
<!--
  Looks like we need to include tsconfig.json explicitly into the project
  (as opposed to being "auto-included" by being in the project's folder),
  for the Visual Studio IntelliSense to pick it up.
-->
<ItemGroup>
  <Content Include="tsconfig.json" />
</ItemGroup>
```

Assuming your TypeScript is installed in `node_modules`, Visual Studio IntelliSense should be able to use it as a language server while respecting the `tsconfig.json`.

Also, I found disabling Resharper's support for TypeScript helpful. Looks like Resharper lags in supporting the latest TypeScript versions. Go to Extensions / Resharper / Options / Products & Features, untick JavaScript and TypeScript.

Restart Visual Studio after all these changes.